# Get rows that doesn't match on another table

Tags: mysql, left-join

I have this working query that generate data the way i like it to happened but now i want it to add another clause statement that will get rows from `tbl_loan_master` that was not on the `tbl_loanledger`.

**Example Data:**

tbl_borrowers

```
------------------------------------------
| id | first_name | last_name | deleted  |
|  1 |     Joe    |   Smith   |    0     |
|  2 |    Lily    |    Mag    |    0     |
|  3 |     Zen    |   Green   |    0     |
|  4 |    Kim     |   Chan    |    0     |
|  5 |    Bob     |   Mac     |    1     |
|  6 |    Ben     |  Cork     |    0     |
------------------------------------------
```

tbl_loan_master

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
| id | borrowers_id |  loan  | date_created |  due_date  |  deleted  |
|  1 |       4      |  300   |   2016/04/28 | 2017/04/28 |     0     |
|  2 |       1      |  100   |   2016/05/05 | 2017/05/05 |     0     |
|  3 |       2      |  500   |   2016/06/08 | 2017/06/08 |     0     |
|  4 |       1      |  200   |   2016/06/13 | 2017/06/13 |     0     |
|  5 |       3      |  150   |   2016/06/15 | 2017/06/15 |     0     |
|  6 |       6      |   50   |   2016/06/16 | 2017/06/16 |     0     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

tbl_loanledger

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| id | borrowers_id | loanmaster_id | payment | balance| date_created | deleted
|  1 |       4      |      1        |    50   |   250  |  2016/05/28  |   0
|  2 |       1      |      2        |    20   |    80  |  2016/05/25  |   0
|  3 |       1      |      2        |    30   |    50  |  2016/06/01  |   0
|  4 |       2      |      3        |   100   |   400  |  2016/06/09  |   0
|  5 |       2      |      3        |    50   |   350  |  2016/06/10  |   0
|  6 |       3      |      4        |    50   |   150  |  2016/06/16  |   0
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Here is the working query:**

```
$query = "SELECT `tbl_borrowers`.* , `tbl_loanledger`.*, `tbl_loan_master`.*
    FROM `tbl_borrowers` 
    LEFT JOIN `tbl_loanledger` 
        ON `tbl_borrowers`.id = `tbl_loanledger`.borrower_id
    LEFT JOIN `tbl_loan_master`
         ON `tbl_loan_master`.id = `tbl_loanledger`.loanmaster_id
    WHERE `tbl_borrowers`.deleted = 0 AND `tbl_loanledger`.deleted = 0 AND MONTH ( `tbl_loanledger`.date_created) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE)
        GROUP BY `tbl_loanledger`.borrower_id 
        ORDER BY `tbl_borrowers`.last_name";
```

The expected result will output the borrowers with their last transaction on the current month (which is June) in loan ledger and also in loans accounts. Like Ben Cork which is not on the loan ledger, he is on the loan accounts but i want to output him on the result set. The deleted column means if it is 0 it indicates it is active if it is 0 it means it has been deleted.

**Expected Result:**

```
|First Name | Last Name |   Due Date   |    Balance     |
|    Ben    |    Cork   |  2017/06/16  |      50        |
|    Joe    |    Smith  |  2017/06/13  |      50        |
|    Lily   |     Mag   |  2017/06/08  |      350       |
|    Zen    |    Green  |  2017/06/15  |      150       |
```

Comment: `select * from tbl_borrowers a left join tbl_loanledger b on a.id=b.borrowers_id where b.id is null`

Comment: I added it as a comment because I'm not quite sure if I understand the question given the query and the sample data and fields on those tables.

Comment: sorry about the confusion @JorgeCampos, i remove some of the code on the query which is not included on  the sample data and fields on the table. When i try to add just the Where `tbl_loanledger`.id is NULL on the existing query, all the records are not showing

Comment: Post your expected result please!

Comment: i added expected result table on the question  @Reno

Answer (score 1):

Try following;)

```
select 
    tb.first_name, tb.last_name, coalesce(tlm.Loan, 0) as Loan, coalesce(t.`Amount Paid`, 0) as `Last Amount Paid`
from tbl_borrowers tb
left join tbl_loan_master tlm
on tb.id = tlm.borrowers_id
left join (
    select t1.*
    from tbl_loanledger t1
    inner join (
        select max(id) as id
        from tbl_loanledger
        group by borrowers_id, loanmaster_id
    ) t2 on t1.id = t2.id
) t
on tb.id = t.borrowers_id
and tlm.id = t.loanmaster_id
```

[**SQLFiddle DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7285eb/6)

Comment: I am very overwhelm with the code and demo you provided @reno, you did exactly what the expected output of the table above but right now i'm having a hard time merging your code with the existing query code i have. If it is ok with you i will update the tables above to the exact details on the record should show?

Comment: i edited the table and also the working query@reno, sorry it took time

Comment: Why 'Joe Smith' has `2017/06/13` for `Due Date`, not `2017/05/05`?

Comment: @zen And you've tried to ask a new question, haven's you? This is totally different from previous one. I think you should ask a new question on SO.

Comment: 2017/06/13 is the due date because he has 2nd transaction on loan master `id` 4 . ahhmmm its actually the same concept with regards on getting rows on certain table but different example. I do understand @reno, by the way thanks for your help earlier.